# Serving Rails through Apache using ProxyPass

Tags: apache-2.2, domain-name-system, ruby-on-rails, proxypass

I have a working rails application that I want to be served through another domain name. So I modified the VirtualHost by adding it as a ServerAlias:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot /home/my/app/public
        ServerName long_server_name.com
        ServerAlias short_name.com
        RewriteEngine On

        ProxyRequests Off
        ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000/
        ProxyPreserveHost on   

         <Proxy *>
          Order deny,allow
          Allow from all
        </Proxy>
</VirtualHost>
```

But, for some odd reason, when I go to short_name.com it gives me the Fedora test page.

I'm able to find documents under /public if i go to them directly (eg. short_name.com/somepage.html). But the requests are not being handled by Rails. Going to the root path should redirect to the login (by rails).

Any ideas? How can I debug what's going on?

(A possible unrelated caveat: 'short_name.com' is a URL that's being leased from someone else as they are the owner.)

Comment: Did you restart apache after adding `ServerAlias`?  Seems like your requests are still getting caught by a default vhost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the basis that you're almost certainly working on the same problem as last time, and don't appear to have worked on most of the issues involved there, I'll reiterate my [previous advice](https://serverfault.com/questions/299921/how-to-setup-2-urls-pointing-to-same-location-in-apache-for-rails/299924#299924):

> It does look like they're proxying.  You can verify this by hitting
>   the site and looking at the source IP -- if it's yours, then they're
>   not proxying, they're doing something *really* weird, otherwise the
>   source IP should be that of their proxy box.  I would imagine that
>   their proxying is probably doing all sorts of unpleasant things to the
>   setup -- if the `Host` header being sent by their proxy server isn't
>   what you're expecting, for instance, then that'll naturally cause
>   problems.  I always log the provided vhost name in my "default vhost"
>   logs for this very reason -- it shows me what people might be hitting
>   me from.
>
> When it comes to the setup, I'd *strongly* recommend getting them to
>   change the DNS to point to your server directly.  That you're
>   "leasing" the domain is irrelevant; DNS can still be managed properly.
>   The only time proxying makes sense is if they're only redirecting part
>   of the site to you, and serving other content on the same domain
>   locally.

Comment: I created a different question because there is new evidence (and I will likely delete the other one). I checked the IP on the request and it IS my IP. Given that I can actually reach the file at the DocRoot, I'm less inclined to think it's a (dns) proxy issue as opposed to an apache proxy issue. I can't obtain the domain name form them (I guess leasing is common so this should work).

Comment: Also, the reason why I created a different question was that I left out the issue of them proxying since I took your advice and verified that my IP was showing up in the access logs. *shrug*

Comment: It ended up being an issue due to the proxying. Blergh. Anyway, this ends up being a dupe of this (I described the issue in detail here) http://serverfault.com/questions/299921/how-to-setup-2-urls-pointing-to-same-location-in-apache-for-rails